# Trace visualization tool (VizTrace) for UnetStack JSON trace files

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to use the `VizTrace` Trace visualization tool. I install Julia on the system successfully. When I am trying with command - `julia --project viztrace.jl trace.jso`. I am getting some errors as shown in the image. Please help to solve these errors.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Paste the error here instead of an image. Also we need a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It would also be useful to have your `trace.json` available somewhere for download, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: ```ERROR: LoadError: KeyError: key "component" not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Dict{String,Any}, ::String) at ./dict.jl:477
 [2] analyze(::Array{Any,1}) at /home/harendra/Documents/3rd sem/Project/try/julia-ms/viztrace.jl:69
 [3] top-level scope at /home/harendra/Documents/3rd sem/Project/try/julia-ms/viztrace.jl:195
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:377
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:288
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:484
in expression starting at /home/harendra/Documents/3rd sem/Project/try/julia-ms/viztrace.jl:195```

Comment: You can find the minimum reproducible example here (including ```trace.json``` file) -: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ypkQeccfKflBqLRhf4xnKfB5ULJ0tseL?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem. If I download your `trace.json` file and run it with the latest `unet-contrib` version of `viztrace.jl`, I get:

```
» julia --project viztrace.jl ~/Downloads/trace.json
Specify a trace:
1: 1644310724592 [B] AddressAllocReq ⟦ node → arp ⟧ (1 events)
2: 1644310724591 [A] AddressAllocReq ⟦ node → arp ⟧ (1 events)
3: 1644310742254 [A] AddressResolutionReq ⟦ websh → arp ⟧ (1 events)
4: 1644310742298 [A] RangeReq ⟦ websh → ranging ⟧ (23 events)
```

I'm running on Julia 1.7.2, but there should be no strong dependency on the exact Julia version.

Try with a fresh copy in a new directory, and make sure you don't have any conflicting packages in your global Julia environment.

Comment: Thank you, sir, The problem was with Julia installation. Previously I install the Julia with command - ```sudo apt install julia``` and version 1.4.1 was installed by default. then I followed ```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iws-Oy4nYc&t=227s&ab_channel=TechWebDocs``` this video for the latest version installation and it worked out

Comment: I am trying to extract the ```end-to-end delay```and ```throughput``` from the output of ```viztrace tool```. I tried to find the time difference between the last and the first events. But I found that the time difference between the last and the first events is not the ``` end-to-end delay```. I want to know, is this the right way or I should follow some other approach.